# multipicklist values order changed when copied over to another record

Tags: picklist, multi-select

I've a multi-picklist field called SegmentA(A,B,C,D) on ObjectA. Also, another multi-picklist field called SegmentB(A,B,C,D) on ObjectB.

Values in both the multi-picklist fields are same.

Selected values on RecordA of ObjectA is showing A,C while Selected values on RecordB of ObjectB is showing C,A.

I'm not able to compare both the values programatically. The order of values given is same.

Below is the code i tried to compare, which is displaying me the result(selected values) in reverse order.

```
String ts = t.AccountSegment__c == null?'NULL':t.AccountSegment__c; 
String qs = o.QuotaSegment__c == null?'NULL':O.QuotaSegment__c;       
System.debug('__AASSDD8.7_'+ts.equals(qs));
```

Any idea on why this order change is happening?

Comment: Please post the code where you are comparing these values. There are probably several different ways of doing it, and the best one depends on what you need to know.

Comment: Below is the code i tried to compare, which is displaying me in reverse order.

Comment: String ts=t.AccountSegment__c==null?'NULL':t.AccountSegment__c;
 String qs = o.QuotaSegment__c == null?'NULL':O.QuotaSegment__c;


 System.debug('_____AASSDD8.7____'+ts.equals(qs));

Comment: Varun - I moved your comments into your question.  On the Salesforce StackExchange you can always edit your question to add more detail instead of commenting. That makes it easier for others to understand your issue.

Comment: @Varun, it looks like there are a bunch of good answers to this question - please help other askers find a good answer by accepting one of them.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate comparison mechanism can be employed here, using the Set type instead of the string.equals method.

You can use the Set<>.containsAll(Set<>) in both directions to check whether both Sets contain the same elements.

```
Set<String> firstSet = new Set<String>('item1;item2;item3;'.split(';'));
Set<String> secondSet = new Set<String>('item2;item1;item3;'.split(';'));
system.debug(firstSet);
system.debug(secondSet);
system.debug(firstSet.containsAll(secondSet) && secondSet.containsAll(firstSet));
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
if (t.AccountSegment__c != null && o.QuotaSegment__c != null) {
    Set<String> firstSet = new Set<String>(t.AccountSegment__c.split(';'));
    Set<String> secondSet = new Set<String>(o.QuotaSegment__c.split(';'));
    system.debug(firstSet);
    system.debug(secondSet);
    system.debug('__AASSDD8.7_' + (firstSet.containsAll(secondSet) && secondSet.containsAll(firstSet)));
}
```

(@Ralph's approach works well too!)

Answer (score 3):

I can't find it documented anywhere, but it appears you can't count on a specific ordering of the multi-select values in the object.  In lieu of comparing the `;`-concatenated version that comes from the database, push them into a set and compare them that way.

**Example**

```
Set<String> tVals = (String.isBlank(t.AccountSegment__c)) 
    ? new Set<String>() 
    : t.AccountSegment__c.split(';');
Set<String> oVals = (String.isBlank(o.QuotaSegment__c)) 
    ? new Set<String>() 
    : o.QuotaSegment__c.split(';');
Set<String> tVals2 = tVals.clone();
Set<String> oVals2 = oVals.clone();
tVals2.removeAll(oVals);
oVals2.removeAll(tVals);
Boolean setsEquals = tVals2.isEmpty() && oVals2.isEmpty();
```

Comment: Thank you Mark and Raplh for your best suggestions. Any idea on why the order of the values we select is different from the order it is copied over to another record's text field through trigger.

Comment: @Varun, there could be any number of reasons why they are in a different order. Most times in situations such as this it is less frustrating to simply control the conditions of the test in order to get accurate behavior from the code. I suspect that this would be documented with the caveat "Do not rely on the order of the elements" if it is written someplace official. If you are able to determine a root cause certainly report it back here.

Answer (score 0):

> I've a multi-picklist field called SegmentA(A,B,C,D) on ObjectA. Also, another multi-picklist field called SegmentB(A,B,C,D) on ObjectB.

This is not unusual behavior from what I discovered when researching this. Depending on your use case, you may find the following of interest. One solution to the problem of copying them from one object to another was as follows below. It is simply a means of "copying" multi-select picklist values from one object to another as **text**:

```
if(ISPICKVAL( Opportunity__r.Project_State__c , "AK") , "AK",
if(ISPICKVAL( Opportunity__r.Project_State__c , "AL") , "AL",
if(ISPICKVAL( Opportunity__r.Project_State__c , "AR") , "AR",
if(ISPICKVAL( Opportunity__r.Project_State__c , "AZ") , "AZ",
if(ISPICKVAL( Opportunity__r.Project_State__c , "CA") , "CA",
```

> I'm not able to compare both the values programatically. The order of
>   values given is same.

I found another "Formula Based" solution on success.salesforce.com I thought worth posting that was in response to the following:

> "We need to create a formula field on a child object that displays all
>   of the selected values from a multi-select picklist on the parent
>   object."

```
IF ( INCLUDES ( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 1" ), "Value 1; ",null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 2" ), "Value 2; ",null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 3" ), "Value 3; ",null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 4" ), "Value 4; ",null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 5" ), "Value 5; ",null )
```

Alternatively, if you want multiple lines displayed, you can do something like this:

```
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 1"), "Value 1", NULL)  + BR() + 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 2"), "Value 2", NULL)  + BR() + 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 3"), "Value 3", NULL)  + BR() + 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 4"), "Value 4", NULL)  + BR() + 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 5"), "Value 5", NULL)
```

or, (which may appear a bit cleaner)...

```
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 1"), "Value 1"  + BR(), NULL) 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 2"), "Value 2"  + BR(), NULL) 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 3"), "Value 3"  + BR(), NULL) 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 4"), "Value 4"  + BR(), NULL) 
IF(INCLUDES( parent.multipicklist__c , "Value 5"), "Value 5", NULL)
```